# gunicorn on linode not launching

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, linode

I'm using gunicorn to deploy my python web application.

When I launch it using this command gunicorn_django -c gunicorn.conf.py, i get this error:

```
root@localhost:/var/www/map01# gunicorn_django -c gunicorn.conf.py
2012-10-14 20:11:32 [4594] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
2012-10-14 20:11:32 [4594] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8888 (4594)
2012-10-14 20:11:32 [4594] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-10-14 20:11:32 [4597] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4597
2012-10-14 20:11:32 [4598] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4598
2012-10-14 20:11:32 [4599] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4599
2012-10-14 15:11:32 [4597] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4597)
2012-10-14 15:11:32 [4598] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4598)
2012-10-14 15:11:32 [4599] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4599)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn_django", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==0.14.6', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn_django')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 132, in run
    DjangoApplication("%prog [OPTIONS] [SETTINGS_PATH]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 124, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 185, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 280, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 328, in stop
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 419, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

This is the gunicorn.conf.py file:

```
bind = u"127.0.0.1:8888"
logfile = u"/var/www/map00/gunicorn.log"
workers = 3
```

On my personal computer, gunicorn work perfectly.
Can someone please give me a hint on what is going on?

Thank you for your time and kind concern.

Jenia Ivlev

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user running gunicorn_django has write access for your logfile

Answer (score 0):

Try running with `--preload` as an argument to `gunicorn_django` - it should show you the error the workers are having when starting. See [this bug](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/338#issuecomment-7425197)